# Minimal API Results.Ok Not Returning Full Object

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

While working on a larger Minimal API project, Results.Ok() was not returning the full object. However, switching to Results.Text() returns the full object.

I've included the full listing of a simple application that I created to see if I can reproduce the behavior. The application includes two endpoints that are supposed to return the same object.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

School school = new School();
school.SchoolName = "My Elementary School";
school.Students.Add(new Student() { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Smith", Grade = 4, StudentID = "123456" });
school.Students.Add(new Student() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", Grade = 5, StudentID = "54321" });

app.MapGet("/SchoolsV1", () =>
{
    return Results.Ok(school);
});

app.MapGet("/SchoolsV2", () =>
{
    string strValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(school, Formatting.Indented);
    return Results.Text(strValue, "application/json", null);
});

app.Run();


public class School
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
}
public class Student
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Using Postman I get the following results.

`https://localhost:7000/SchoolsV1`

```
{
    "schoolName": "My Elementary School"
}
```

Then

`https://localhost:7000/SchoolsV2`

```
{
    "Students": [
        {
            "StudentID": "123456",
            "FirstName": "Bill",
            "LastName": "Smith",
            "Grade": 4
        },
        {
            "StudentID": "54321",
            "FirstName": "Jane",
            "LastName": "Doe",
            "Grade": 5
        }
    ],
    "SchoolName": "My Elementary School"
}
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there something I'm missing when using Results.Ok()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Results.Ok` (which is actually not needed here, you can use just `app.MapGet("/SchoolsV1", () => school`) uses the default `System.Text.Json` serializer (more info about it can be found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0)) which does not serialize fields by default. There are several options.

Easiest one is to change `School.Students` to be a property:

```cs
public class School
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; } = new List<Student>();
}
```

Or configure `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions`:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(opts => opts.SerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true);
var app = builder.Build();
// ...
```